# Keeping a fork of a repository up-to-date with upstream changes

Tags: git, versioning, release-management

I have a repository, which is a fork of a public project. The fork contains several additional commits with custom features - nothing fancy. Recently, I have been wondering what would be the best approach of incorporating upstream changes into the fork. Currently the setup looks like the following:

1. The fork has the `master` branch with these additional commits and another branch that acts like a staging branch (let's call it `staging`).
2. Every now and then I check if anything new has been released in the upstream repository.
3. If yes, then I rebase `staging` first (staging also contains all these additional commits). This results in a GitLab pipeline which builds a Docker image and pushes it to a Docker repo with `staging` tag. After that, a k8s deployment is restarted and the new changes are available in the `staging` environment.
4. If everything is fine, I repeat the same process but this time I rebase fork's `master` against upstream `master` (sometimes I simply reset `--hard` `master` to `staging`).

I feel like the whole process needs a bit of improvement. I was thinking about using custom tags in my fork, but these would be kind of "lost" with every rebase.

Comment: This is a textbook case for using "merge" instead of "rebase".

Comment: Supporting @pjc50's observation; is there any reason you're choosing to rebase? Do you have a need to somehow interleave the commits of your code and that of the original repo?

Comment: I like having my git history clean thus I have decided to use the rebase workflow. It feels to me that using `merge` workflow in that case would complicate things a bit. The thing is that I add new commits very sporadically to my fork and they are always on top of the branch - that is what seemed to be the simplest and cleanest solution for me.

Comment: I've honestly never heard of anyone using anything other than merge for this purpose...